# MySQL Arithmetic with FLOOR result does not increment

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, floating-point, integer-arithmetic

I have a procedure where I am incrementing an ID manually, by adding a random number to the ID value iteratively. Occasionally this results in the the ID not incrementing, even though I can confirm that the statement `(FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-2+1))+2)` always returns a value between 2-1000. And yet the following simple statement:

```
SET `nextid` = `nextid` + (FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-2+1))+2);
```

Still fails to increment `nextid` from time to time. If I separate my `(FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-2+1))+2)` value into a separate variable and add the two variables this does not happen. Below is a minimal example test case that reproduces the behaviour.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `nextid` BIGINT DEFAULT 793991813529600000;
    DECLARE `previous` BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `i` BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `random` BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

    WHILE `i` < 100000 DO
        SET `previous` = `nextid`;
        -- Produce a random number between 2 and 1000.
        SET `random` = (FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-2+1))+2);
        SET `nextid` = `nextid` + `random`;

        -- Error if the nextid is no different from the previous ID.
        -- This is successful every time. 
        IF `nextid` = `previous` THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Oh no!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 2000;
        END IF;

        SET `i` = `i` + 1;
    END WHILE;

    SET `i` = 0;
    WHILE `i` < 100000 DO
        SET `previous` = `nextid`;
        -- Increment the ID by a random number and do the set in a single statment.
        SET `nextid` = `nextid` + (FLOOR(RAND()*(1000-2+1))+2);

        -- This fails randomly, but reliably.
        IF `nextid` = `previous` THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Whoops!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 2000;
        END IF;

        SET `i` = `i` + 1;
    END WHILE;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL `test`();
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`;
```

It looks like it might be some kind of casting issue, but I can't find anything to confirm. So my question is, what is causing this behaviour?

Additional details;

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what most likely happens:

- `RAND()` returns a float
- `FLOOR(FLOAT VALUE)` returns a float
- `BIGINT VALUE + FLOAT VALUE` returns a float
- **Floats are not precise and that is where you have problem**

One of the nextid values that failed for me is 793991813579709184. See what happens when you add 50f to it... the float value does not increment:

```
CREATE TABLE t (i BIGINT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (793991813579709184);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (793991813579709184 + 50e0);
SELECT * FROM t;
```

```
| 793991813579709184 |
| 793991813579709184 |
```

In your test code I changed this line and it worked as expected:

```
SET `nextid` = `nextid` + CAST(RAND() * 999 AS SIGNED) + 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, that had been bugging me all morning. So, does this mean that when the result of an operation can not be represented by the type of result, the operation is effectively ignored? Or is it just that it happens to be the highest possible value for a float and there is no overflow behaviour?

Comment: No. (i) when operand datatypes are mixed MySQL uses some rules to determine the datatype of output (it is usually described in manual) (ii) adding int and float results in a float (this rule is documented) (iii) floats are approximations of the value they (are supposed to) represent. So adding 793991813579709184 + 50 should result in 793991813579709234 but then this number is approximated and the approximation becomes 793991813579709184. If you added some bigger number e.g. 65 then the result could be different but not exactly accurate.

Comment: Floating-point **numbers** are not approximations of the numbers they represent. Per the IEEE-754 standard, each floating-point datum (that represents a number, rather than a NaN or infinity) represents one number exactly. Floating-point **operations** round the exact mathematical results to results representable in the floating-point format. So the errors occur in operations (including conversion of decimal numerals to binary floating-point), not in numbers. This distinction is essential for writing proofs or crafting algorithms using floating-point.